# Enumerating through list of expressions to filter collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I'm pushing the limits of my knowledge in c# and linq here, so please bear with me if I'm completely off with my example or understanding of linq, c#, generic types, lambda expressions,design patterns, etc.

I have a class that holds two collections, one is the collection to be filtered: `IEnumberable<InstagramUser>` and the second is the collection of expressions to filter on: `IEnumerable<IInstagramFilter>`.

```
public class InstagramDisplay {

    public IEnumerable<InstagramUser> instagramUsers;
    public IEnumerable<IInstagramFilter> instagramFilters; 

    public InstagramDisplay() {
        instagramUsers = new List<InstagramUser>();
        instagramFilters = new List<IInstagramFilter>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<InstagramUser> display() {
        instagramFilters.ToList().ForEach(x => instagramUsers.Where(x.filter(instagramUsers)));
        return instagramFilters;
    }
}

public interface IInstagramFilter {
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter<T>(IQueryable<T> source); 
}
```

I would have classes extend `IInstagramFilter`. Each `IInstagramFilter` class would have a property (or function - not sure what's best) that would return the lambda expression that would be applied to `IEnumerable<InstagramUser>` in the `display()` method.

```
public class UserFilter : IInstagramFilter {
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter<T>(IQueryable<T> source) {
        //return some expression - but how?
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to understand a few things:

1. How to set the expression for each `IInstagramFilter` class and then call it in the `display()` method?
2. Each `IInstagramFilter` class would have a lambda that would be used to filter `IEnumerable<InstagramUser>` but since the Filter class has no knowledge of `IEnumerable<InstagramUser>` how would I create the appropriate lambda in the first place?
3. I think this roughly follows the Decorator Pattern but perhaps there's a better design all together that I'm not aware of.

**UPDATED CODE**

Based on Olivier's answer this is what I have now. On the return for `display()` I'm getting the error when using `.Where(filter)`

> The type arguments for method '`System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)`' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
public class InstagramDisplay {

    public IEnumerable<InstagramUser> instagramUsers;
    public List<Expression<Func<InstagramUser, bool>>> instagramFilters; 

    public InstagramDisplay() {
        instagramUsers = new List<InstagramUser>();
        instagramFilters = new List<Expression<Func<InstagramUser, bool>>>();
    }

    public void addFilter(Expression<Func<InstagramUser, bool>> filter) {
        instagramFilters.Add(filter);
    }

    public IEnumerable<InstagramUser> display() {
        return instagramFilters.SelectMany(filter => instagramUsers.Where(filter)).Distinct(); //error on this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to decide whether you want to perfom some action or whether you want to return something. `List<T>.ForEach()` performs an action on each item but has a void return type and does not return anything.

This `IInstagramFilter` interface seems superfluous to me. You can declare a filter list like this

```
var userFilters = new List<Expression<Func<InstagramUser, bool>>>();
userFilters.Add(u => u.Name.StartsWith("A"));
userFilters.Add(u => u.Score >= 100);
```

If you have a source of users you can do something like this to all users returned by all filters

```
IQueryable<InstagramUser> usersSource = ...; 
// Or IEnumerable<InstagramUser> for LINQ to objects
// if you drop the Expression<> part.

var users = userFilters.SelectMany(f => usersSource.Where(f));
```

`SelectMany` flattens the nested enumerations. The example returns all users whos name starts with "A" or who have a score >= 100. This might return a user twice, therfore I would suggest to append a `.Distinct()`

```
var users = userFilters
    .SelectMany(f => usersSource.Where(f))
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: I agree that `IInstagramFilter` is unnecessary here.  Instead of `SelectMany` couldn't he loop over the collection of filters, appending the `.Where(filter)` to `userSource`.  This would prevent duplicate users, and also chain the filters together using "and" instead of "or"

Comment: @MikeC: Chaining the filters together is a very good idea, since it makes the `Distinct()` superfluous. I am not sure if the OP wants them ORed or ANDed (from his example I assumed ORed). AND is easy (just chain `Wheres`, OR is more difficult.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes This is an excellent answer. I've posted my updated code above, but I'm still getting an error on the return statement for `display()`

Comment: C# is good in inferring type arguments, but in a few cases it fails to do so. Then you must specify them explicitly `return instagramFilters.SelectMany<Expression<Func<InstagramUser, bool>>, InstagramUser>(filter => instagramUsers.Where(filter)).Distinct();`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Do I have to use `Expression<Func<>>`? I'm getting an error when doing `.Where(filter)` but if I change `instagramFilters` to `List<Func<InstagramUser,bool>> then I can compile. Whether I it actually filters the list I'm unsure of yet. I thought I understood that expression trees had to be used when being passed to linq as a lambda, am I wrong about that?

Comment: When I change to `Func<>` it doesn't filter the collection.

Comment: It depends whether you have a `IEnumerable<T>` or a `IQueryable<T>` as source. `IEnumerable<T>` is used for LINQ-to-objects and requires a `Func<T,bool>`. You can apply it to collections. `IQueryable<T>` is used for LINQ-to-databases like Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL and requires `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` as parameter to `Where`.